# NPE in mocked method using PowerMock

Tags: junit, powermock, easymock

I am looking to mock the output of a method call using PowerMock. My class looks like this:

```
    public class TestEasyMock {

    private static TestEasyMock TEST_INSTANCE = new TestEasyMock();

    public static TestEasyMock getInstance() {
        return TEST_INSTANCE;
    }

    private Cache<String, String> first = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().
            maximumSize(8192).expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
    private Set<String> second = new TreeSet<String>();

    public String testMethod (String testParam) {
        return first.getIfPresent(testParam);
   }
}
```

The test I run throws NPE in the testMethod call and it seems that first field is null. Since testMethod is mocked, I was expecting that testMethod is not actually called but directly returns what's instructed to. The test I'm running is:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TestEasyMock.class})
public class EasyMockTest {
    @Test
    public void firstTest (){

    suppress(constructor(TestEasyMock.class));
        TestEasyMock testObject = PowerMock.createStrictPartialMockForAllMethodsExcept(TestEasyMock.class, "testMethod");
        EasyMock.expect(testObject.testMethod("blabla")).andReturn("blaTwice");
        EasyMock.replay(testObject);

        String result = TestUtils.replaceString("replaceable");
        assertEquals("replaceable(blaTwice)", result);

    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: **1)** What's the exact stacktrace? **2)** How does `TestUtils.replaceString("replaceable");` fit in?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `PowerMock.createStrictPartialMockForAllMethodsExcept(TestEasyMock.class, "testMethod");`, you specify that testMethod should **not** be mocked. See [the description of the method](https://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.0/apidocs/org/powermock/PowerMock.html#createStrictPartialMockForAllMethodsExcept%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...%29) in the PowerMock API docs.